# Problem in handling many field through function in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I want to generate field in mongoose with function.
Because there are many fields, but they are much the same, I wanna use function to create them to keep code short.

I wrote a function, but there exists lints.

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose'

function fieldGen(name, type="string", isRequired=true) {
   var field = {}
   field[name] = {
      type: type,
      required: isRequired
   }
   return {...field}
}

const testSchema = new Schema({
   fieldGen("firstname")
   fieldGen("lastname")
   fieldGen("location")
})
```

In VS Code, Problem shows as below

`Identifier expected. ts(1003) [20, 12]`

I expect first argument "firstname" matches name in function, and return object.

Comment: Objects consist of key-value pairs, not just values.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding values to your `testSchema` object without giving them names.

Also, you're spreading the properties of the `field` object into a new object literal. That doesn't accomplish anything. Just returning the `field` object would yield the same result.

I see what you are trying to do. If you debug this in smaller steps and take a closer look at the data you are handling, I think you'll figure it out on your own.